# Почему не работает AJAX скрипт в firefox?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, html5, firefox

Добрый день! Подскажите, почему нможет не работать AJAX скрипт в firefox?
Скрипт отвечает за отправку данных формы(добавление товара в корзину), в Опере и Хроме все нормально. А в firefox форма перенаправляет на ссылку в action из за чего я получаю 404 и товар в корзину не попадает.

```
$('.main-wrap').on('submit','form#add-product',function() {
event.preventDefault();
var a = null,
    e = null,
    t = $(this),
    n = t.find('button[type="submit"]'),
    r = t.find('input[name="variant"]:checked'),
    s = t.find('select[name="variant"]'),
    i = t.find('select[name="size"]'),
    u = t.find('input[name="size"]:checked'),
    l = t.find('input[name="amount"]');
console.log(a = r.val());
console.log(e = u.val());
console.log(l.val());
r.size() > 0 && (a = r.val()),
l.size() > 0 && (amount = l.val()),
s.size() > 0 && (a = s.val()),
u.size() > 0 && u.val() > 0 && (e = u.val()),
i.size() > 0 && (e = i.val()), 0 != e ? $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/cart.php",
    data: {
        variant: a,
        size: e,
        amount: amount
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(a) {
        // $(".error-message").hasClass("size-error") && $(".error-message").removeClass("size-error"),
        console.log(a['c']);
        console.log(a['p']);
        $(".cart-btn").html(a['c']).addClass('cart--active');
        $('.popup__body').html(a['p']);
    }
}) : $(".error-message").addClass("size-error")
```

});

```
<form id="add-product" action="/cart">
      {if $product->sizes|count > '1'}
      <div class="product__size-list">
        {foreach $product->sizes as $v}
        <input id="size-n-{$v->size_id}" class="product__size-checkbox display--hidden" name="size" type="radio" value="{$v->size_id}">
        <label for="size-n-{$v->size_id}" class="product__size-item">
            {$v->scale}{if $v->growth}&nbsp;({$v->growth}){/if}
        </label>
        {/foreach}
      </div>
      {/if}
      <div style="display: none;">
        <input name="variant" value="{$product->variant->id}" type="radio" checked style="display: none;" />
      </div>
      <div class="product__quantity">
        <span class="btn-m btn-minus">
          <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>

        <input class="display--hidden" type="text" name="amount" value="1">

        <span class="quantity__count">1</span>
        <span class="btn-m btn-plus">
          <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Firefox нет глобального объекта `event`. К счастью, обработчики событий jQuery получают его первым параметром во всех браузерах.

```
$('.main-wrap').on('submit','form#add-product',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Comment: И что делать? как запустить, что бы все работало?

Comment: @AFI19 хм, я же написал. Внимательно сравните Ваши и мои строчки кода. Ладно, первую строчку :).

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Сразу не заметил.