# Постраничный вывод данных ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

В общем, сделал я постраничный вывод, который успешно работал со всеми условиями выборки(в форме можно выбрать фильтр, сортировку, дату и выводит все как нужно), но когда решил сделать все через ajax столкнулся с трудностью, которая заключается в том, что вывод данных происходит только после нажатия на кнопку, тогда и появляется вся выборка(по 10 записей на страницу) и сама постраничная навигация вместе с выборкой. На ajax выборка выводится при помощи json и все работает, а вот как отобразить функцию, которая выводит постраничную навигацию я ума не приложу. вот код js:

```
$("#sortfilt").submit(function(e) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var showusers = 'showusers';
        var sort = $('#sort').val();
        var filtgroup = $('#filtgroup').val();
        var datefrom = $('#datefrom').val();
        var dateto = $('#dateto').val();

        $.get("ajax.php", {showusers: showusers, sort: sort, filtgroup: filtgroup, datefrom: datefrom, dateto: dateto}, function (data) {
            alert(data);
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(data);
            $('#users').empty();
            for(var key in data) {
                var obj = (key, data[key]);
                $('#users').append("<ul><li><img src=" + obj.imageExtention + "></li><li>" + obj.login + "</li> <li>" + obj.name + "</li> <li>" + obj.email + "</li> <li>" + obj.expirationDateAndTime + "</li> <li><button name='delete' value='" + obj.consumerId + "'>Удалить</button></li></ul>");
            }
        });
    });
```

а вот ajax.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['showusers'])) {
    $data = array();
    if($_GET['sort']) {
        $sort = $db->escape($_GET['sort']);
        $order = " ORDER BY $sort ASC";//формируем запрос
    }

    if($_GET['filtgroup'] === 'all') {
        $filter = "";
    } else {
        $filt = $db->escape($_GET['filtgroup']);
        $filter = "AND consumer.groupId = '$filt'";//формируем запрос
    }

    if($_GET['datefrom'] && $_GET['dateto']) {
        $from = $db->escape($_GET['datefrom']);
        $to = $db->escape($_GET['dateto']);
        $datequery = "AND consumer.expirationDateAndTime BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'";//добавляем продолжнение запроса на дату, если она введена
    } else {
        $datequery = "";
    }
    // Подготовка к постраничному выводу
    $perpage = 10; // Количество отображаемых данных из БД

    if (empty(@$_GET['page']) || ($_GET['page'] <= 0)) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = (int) $_GET['page']; // Считывание текущей страницы
    }
    // Общее количество информации
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($db->query('SELECT * FROM `consumer`')) or die('error! Записей не найдено!');
    $pages_count = ceil($count / $perpage); // Количество страниц
    // Если номер страницы оказался больше количества страниц
    if ($page > $pages_count) {
        $page = $pages_count;
    }
    $start_pos = ($page - 1) * $perpage; // Начальная позиция, для запроса к БД
    //$boom = Reg::linkbar($page, $pages_count);
    function linkbar($page, $pages_count) {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $pages_count; $j++) {
        // Вывод ссылки
            if ($j == $page) {
                echo ' <a style="color: #808000;" >'.$j.'</a> ';
            } else {
                echo ' <a style="color: #808000;" href='.$_SERVER['php_self'].'?page='.$j.'&showusers>'.$j.'</a> ';//возможно после showusers нужно добавить ='.$j.'
            }
        // Выводим разделитель после ссылки, кроме последней
        // например, вставить "|" между ссылками
            if ($j != $pages_count) {
                echo ' | ';
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    //Выводим запрос
    $res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `consumer`, `group` WHERE consumer.groupId = group.groupId $filter $datequery $order LIMIT ".$start_pos.", ".$perpage);//$filter $datequery $order
    //var_dump($res);
    while(($row = $db->fetch_assoc($res)) != false) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

также в этом файле и есть функция linkbar(), которая выводит навигацию и я не понимаю, как ухватится за эту функцию, что навигация выводилась вместе с выборкой

Comment: Первое же что бросилось в глаза: в первой строке в функцию передаётся аргумент `e`, а во второй используется уже `event`. Так и задумано и event существует где-то выше?

Comment: Да, работает, отменяет действие по умолчанию, так и задумано

Comment: @myfavoritename http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590919/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-ajax-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B2-firefox/590922#590922

Answer (score 1):

Если алгоритмически.
Как минимум, AJAX должен в запросе передавать номер текущей страницы `page` - тогда сервер будет формировать ответ для "нужной" страницы.
Для отрисовки пейджинга нужно сделать отдельную функцию (аналог linkbar()) на клиенте, которую вызывать в теле success от AJAX. При нажатии на страницу пейджинга нужно вызывать AJAX с соответствующей нажатию `page` и по success отмечать активной страницу в пейджинге.
По-хорошему, сервер в ответе должен отдавать общее количество строк и номер страницы которую он отдал, чтобы удобнее было отрисовывать блок пейджинга на клиенте.

Comment: К примеру в функции после цикла указать функцию page() и дальше 

function page() {

   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "index.php",
    success: function() {
     //.....
    }
   });
  }

я вас правильно понял? Если так, то как мне написать функцию на подобие linkbar() в jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример моего кода для динамической загрузки контента. Данный код работает с загрузкой фотографий с определенного альбома:

```
 _prototype.getPhotosFromAlbum = function (album_id, page) {

        var imageBlock = '<div class="col s12 m3" style="text-align: center">' +
            '<div class="card-panel white">' +
            '<img src="{0}" alt="">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

        $.get('/api/albums/' + album_id + '/photos/' + page, function (response) {

            if (page == 1) {
                $('div.album-photos').empty();
            }

            if (response.photos.length > 0) {
                $.each(response.photos, function (i, photo) {
                    $('div.album-photos').append(imageBlock.replace('{0}', photo.url));
                });
            }

            if (response.photos.length == 8) {
                $('div.album-photos').append('<div class="row"><div style="text-align: center">' +
                    '<button class="btn btn-primary load-more-photos" data-album-id="' + album_id + '" data-page="' + (page + 1) + '">' +
                    'Завантажити більше фото' +
                    '</button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>');

                $('button.load-more-photos').on('click', function () {
                    _prototype.getPhotosFromAlbum($(this).data('album-id'), $(this).data('page'));
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }

        });
    };
```